# How is multipart formdata works?

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, react-native, axios

This is my first time trying to upload an image using a FormData. Basically it's a POST method with headers: `content-type: 'multipart/form-data'` and a request body which is as below:

```
const data = new FormData();

data.append('someKey', {"amount": "300"});
data.append('photo', {
                       filename: 'file_a.png', 
                       type: 'image/png', 
                       uri: /Users/isaac/Library/...../file.png 
});
```

When data without the key `photo`, it seems to be working fine, however when key `photo` being added, server will throw error code 500. I'm wondering which part might have gone wrong?

I've also tried `content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and data remain the same way but both results are the same, giving me the error 500?

Comment: Can you log the error on the server?

Comment: @Roi: Not possible at the moment as it's handle by backend team. Before proceeding that, i'll wish to make sure that I am 100% correct synthetically on my side

Comment: Can you try to surround all your fields in quoutes like you do with the object above. So it will be "filename": "file_a.png", "type": "image/png", "uri" "/Users..."

Comment: Let me be hard on the code here. You have shown frontend code but not backend code. Strongly type languages can be pathetic managing uploads. Even if you miss something in terms of type from frontend they will throw 500 error if your backend rest API is not designed up to standards. Backend looks easy but can be difficult if not done right or done by a novoice. Can you also put what is needed as per backend documentation? Documentation is most important so is it in your question. Please add swagger or open API rest API requirements documentation. It will help others as well to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `500` response from a server complying with the HTTP spec means *something* went wrong on the server, and it's not your fault. Without any context in the response, it's basically impossible to tell what the "something" was. You need to ask your backend team to resolve the error. A `400` response would indicate the fault was on your end.

If your server isn't complying with the HTTP spec, then responses mean whatever the backend team wants them to mean. If they haven't told you, you have to ask them. Either way, you need to talk to the backend team.